# javascript error while running application

Tags: javascript

```
C:\Users\Vicky\workspace\LearningJavaScript\first.html:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { <!DOCTYPE html>
                                                              ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Comment: could you provide some code?

Comment: see the `^` ... it's telling you exactly where the error is ... why do you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the middle of your javascript?

Comment: This is the code i have written

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content_type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <style>  
 span{
 background-color: #0066AA;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-weight: bold;
 <script>

Comment: function moveIt(){
 
 
 var coords = new Array(10,50,100,130,175,225,260,300,320,350);
 var x = coords[Math.floor((Math.random()*10))];
 var y = coords[Math.floor((Math.random()*10))];
 $("#elusiveText").css({"top": x + "px", "left": y + "px"})
 }
    </script>
 <style>

Comment: span{
         background-color: #0066AA;
         color: #FFFFFF;
         font-weight: bold;
         border-color: #C0C0C0;
         border:2px solid;
         border-radius:5px;
         padding: 3px;
         position:absolute;
         top:150px;
         left:100px;
       } 
   
    </style>
   </head>
<body>
       <span id="elusiveText" onmouseover="moveIt()">Click Me</span>
      </body>
    </html>

Comment: The above three messages are the code that I have written and the original post is the error that I get.  I would like to tell you that I am getting the same error for all the files that I run.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend removing this `<!DOCTYPE html>` from your javascript.

i.e. `(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ... });`

I would guess this is because you need JQuery, among other things, for Bootstrap to work.

Try adding this to your code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

It can also be found [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/)!

Comment: I removed the <!DOCTYPE html> but I get this error C:\Users\Vicky\workspace\LearningJavaScript\first.html:2
<html>
^

Comment: I would like to clarify that I have 3 files out of which two are .js extensions and one is .html extension. The .js file runs fine but the .html file gives error. I cant figure out why. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

From the comments(by you in your own post(**The Code**)), I made little edits.
**The possible isssue is without calling jQuery Library, you are using it. Check it now**

```js
function moveIt(){ 
var coords = new Array(10,50,100,130,175,225,260,300,320,350);
var x = coords[Math.floor((Math.random()*10))];
var y = coords[Math.floor((Math.random()*10))]; $("#elusiveText").css({"top": x + "px", "left": y + "px"});
}
```

```css
span{ background-color: #0066AA;
          color: #FFFFFF;
          font-weight: bold;
          border-color: #C0C0C0;
          border:2px solid;
          border-radius:5px;
          padding: 3px;
          position:absolute;
          top:150px;
          left:100px;
    }
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <span id="elusiveText" onmouseover="moveIt()">Click Me</span> </body>
```

Comment: I am using eclipse. When I open in browser it shows only "click me" as text but it does not move as it does in your post.

Comment: which browser you are using?

Comment: Both firefox and chrome and I am still getting the warning that i got initially

Comment: Possibilites :   
1 . The jQuery CDN may block your request  
2. The firewall block your browser from accessing the CDN.  
Solutions :  
Try saving the copy of jQuery to local and add it to script

Comment: I am new to java script,infact this is the first time I am learning javascript. Can u mention the detailed procedure , how to save jQuery to local and add it to script. Thanks

Comment: go to this link : https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js
press ctrl+s and it will saved as a JavaScript file(.js), then copy the file to the folder where this HTML file resides. In your `script` tag, change value of `src` to `"jquery.min.js"` that is `src="jquery.min.js"`

Comment: I am still getting this error                                                   C:\Users\Vicky\workspace\LearningJavaScript\first.html:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { <!DOCTYPE html>
                                                              ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)

Comment: I am only getting "Click me" as text in the output and it does not move as it does in your reply. at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3

Comment: update question with full code. I think there are more code including bootstrap and some third parties

Comment: This is the code for the other file js_errors.html. Here in Google chrome I can see the "Click me" text and in the developer tools- console I can see Page loaded but nothing for the click it  method.<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    function loadedFunction(){
    console.log("Page is Loaded");
     }
      function clickItNow(){
           console.log("User Clicked");
      }
     </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="loadedFunction()">
   <span onclick="clickIt()">Click Me</span>
 </body>
 </html>

Comment: which server s/w you use. Node Js?

Comment: This is the code for  my html file first.html      <!DOCTYPE html><html>  <head>  <meta charset="utf-8" /><script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>     <script>   function moveIt(){      var coords = new Array(10,50,100,130,175,225,260,300,320,350);     var x = coords[Math.floor((Math.random()*10))];         var y = coords[Math.floor((Math.random()*10))];        $("#elusiveText").css({"top": x + "px", "left": y + "px"})12       }     </script>     <style>     span{      background-color: #0066AA;         color: #FFFFFF;    font-weight: bold;        border-color:

Comment: #C0C0C0;         border:2px solid;         border-radius:5px;         padding: 3px;         position:absolute;         top:150px;         left:100px;     }    </style>   </head>   <body>     <span id="elusiveText" onmouseover="moveIt()">Click Me</span>   </body></html>     In the cod eabove I can see "Click Me" text in the browser and no color no moving of the "Click Me" text also

Comment: This is the error that I get in Eclipse when I run  the File C:\Users\Vicky\workspace\LearningJavaScript\lesson02\js_errors.html:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { <!DOCTYPE html>
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)

Comment: at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3

Comment: try replacing the entire content on the page with the answer and check it. the problem may be with jQuery

Comment: I wanted to tell you one more thing, that when I run the application in Eclipse, I right click the file and the file is under Node Application. The .js file runs fine but the .html file gives the error.

Comment: The issue is with node. Node Js is a server side scripting language and here, you don't have to use Node Js. Come out of eclipse, place it using notepad , save it as .html and run. (OR) instead of run from eclipse, just double click the .html file

Comment: C:\Users\Vicky\workspace\LearningJavaScript\lesson01\Stackfirst.html:9       background-color: #0066AA;
                       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3

Comment: I have posted the above error that I got on executing the answer. I am using Nodejs server

Comment: try the following
1 . copy the code above.
2 . open notepad
3 . paste it and save it as something.html
4 . double click on it.
Now if you get any error, let me know. You don't have to compile front end JavaScript

Comment: I ran the same code in notepad file I still got only "Click Me" text. I have posted the above error that I got on executing the answer. I am using Nodejs server

Comment: I ran the code in anotepad file but got only "Click Me" text which I was getting in the Browser also. However I did not get any error. But I want the code to behave along with the mouseiver also so the the button moves whenever mouse hovers on it.

Comment: why you are using Node JS?

Comment: How come the code that you have written in the answer works fine. How is it different from my code. And which IDE are you using to run the code?

Comment: Actually I am referring an ebook by sams self learning in which they teach html,javascript, AngularJS all front end languages and in that they have told to install node.js

Comment: node JS is like PHP. in Node JS, you can write JavaScript code for backend. It is not required if you don't want to do so.

Comment: VS Code and Notepad is good companion. anyway you can try Dreamweaver or Notepad++ or Intellij Idea

Comment: my email is mirchandani123@yahoo.com, if it is possible for you, please email me a test mail, i will send u that book. You have to open that book using adobe digital editions software.

Comment: I am a.NET developer so I use Visual studio, so i will download VS code. But I will miss teh settings required to be made because in the book I am referring only eclipse is mentioned..ALso I wanted to ask that all of the AngularJS, Javascript and jquery can be written in VS code?

Comment: in HTML , JavaScript and .NET, you don't need eclipse. you can use Visual Studio

Comment: and for jquery and angularjs? which s/w would u recommend?

Comment: same for all. jQuery and angular Js are just libraries. not standalone languages

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137170/discussion-on-answer-by-sagar-v-javascript-error-while-running-application).